# Angular login in users with local storage, nothing stored

Tags: angular, authentication, local-storage

I'm trying to log in users with Angular (6.0.2) and I'm doing this by saving "current user" to local storage, but nothing gets stored. Here's the code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators'
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Userlogon } from '../_models/Userlogon';
import { User } from '../_models/User';

const HttpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ "Content-type": "application/json" })
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  loginobject: any;
  private usersUrl= '/api/v1/accounts/';
  private logonUrl= '/api/v1/auth/login/';
  private logoutUrl= '/api/v1/auth/logout/';

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  login(username: string, password: string) {
    this.loginobject=JSON.stringify({"username": username, "password": password});
    return this.http.post<any>(this.logonUrl, this.loginobject, HttpOptions)
      .pipe(map(user => {
        if (user && user.token){
          localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
          return console.log(user);
        }
      }));
  }

  logout(){
    localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
    return this.http.get<any>(this.logoutUrl).subscribe(response => console.log(response));
  }
}
```

And here is the Auth-Guard:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../_services/auth.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
  ) { }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot){
    if(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')){
      return true;
    }
    this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl : state.url }});
    return false;
  }
}
```

It returns a console log of the authenticated user from the back-end which luckily works as intented but nothing is stored locally. Is there something that should be enabled for me to be able to store things locally, or is it something else that might be wrong?

Picture of debugger: [image]

Picture of console log at login:
[image]

Comment: On the browser debugger on the storage shows the key and some kind of data like [object Object]?

Comment: @UlyssesMarx Added a picture of it, there's stuff there but not anything i recognize. It's supposed to be named currentUser.

Comment: are you sure that the code enter here if (user && user.token){
          localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
          return console.log(user);
        }

Comment: The map operator is returning undefined as console.log does not return anything!

Comment: @Luillyfe The console log is returning the logged in user from the back-end. Changing it to return user; doesn't help either.

Comment: So your response is empty or the user response doen't validate properly.
What did you get with :
`.pipe(map(user => {
console.log(user);
      }));`

Comment: Same, it logs the correct user from the back-end

Comment: @UlyssesMarx the problem was the user.token if statement, which wasn't satisfied, any clues on why?

Comment: javascrypt is so sensitive on validations you can do it like i did on this project:
`if(typeof nextProps.token !== 'undefined' && nextProps.token !== null && nextProps.token !== '') `